# No puedo obtener la información de una smartcard

Tags: java, android, smartcard

Tengo el siguiente problema, he estado intentando e investigando durante varios días sobre cómo obtener datos de una tarjeta inteligente, la tarjeta es para `ic` por contacto, no por `nfc`, aquí hago la solicitud de la siguiente manera:

> 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x31, 0x50, 0x41, 0x59, 0x2E,
>   0x53, 0x59, 0x53, 0x2E, 0x44, 0x44, 0x46, 0x30, 0x31, 0X00

Que me da esta [respuesta](http://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/?data=6f22840e315041592e5359532e4444463031a5108801015f2d066573656e70749f1101019000):

Según `GlobalPlatform Card Specification 2.2.1` dice que las formas de obtener datos de la tarjeta, con el comando`Get Data`:

Los dominios de seguridad admitirán al menos las siguientes etiquetas de objetos de datos:

- Etiqueta '42': Número de identificación del emisor (o Número de identificación del proveedor del dominio de seguridad);
- Etiqueta '45': Número de imagen de la tarjeta (o Número de imagen del dominio de seguridad);
- Etiqueta '66': Datos de la tarjeta (o Datos de administración del dominio de seguridad);
- Etiqueta 'E0': Plantilla de información clave.

Un dominio de seguridad puede admitir las siguientes etiquetas de objetos de datos:

- Etiqueta 'D3': Nivel de seguridad actual;
- Etiqueta '2F00': Lista de aplicaciones que pertenecen al dominio de seguridad, o todas las aplicaciones en la tarjeta

si el dominio de seguridad tiene privilegio de registro global;

- Etiqueta 'FF21': Información de recursos de tarjeta extendida disponible para Card Content Management, como se define en ETSI TS 102 226.

Las implemento de esta manera:

```
(byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xCA, 0x00, 0x42, 0x00

(byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xCA, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00

(byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xCA, 0x00, 0x66, 0x00

(byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xCA, 0x00, (byte) 0xE0

(byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA5
```

Ninguno me da los datos deseados, el único que lo hace es `tag 42` (Etiqueta 42), esto estoy comprobando [aquí](http://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/)

Necesito obtener el nombre del titular de la tarjeta, el número de la tarjeta y la fecha de vencimiento, pero no puedo obtener ningún valor o información que me acerque a esto, gracias de antemano.